# I have a dropdown list with Pre-filled Values in Angular. Now on basis of the value selected in that I want to render the next division

Tags: angular

So here is the example of the List I have
[image: list present in form]

Now whenever I select any of these Field in my form, on the basis of value selected here, I want to load the next div in my form. Can you please suggest any idea for this usecase? Tried *ngIF, but I guess , I am not knowing a proper way to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an EventListener, that fires an Event every time an item is selected or the selection has changed. I think its called onchange. You can then write a function in which you load the next div or do whatever you want to do according to what has been changed. Everytime the event is fired you would call that function.

There should probably be also an angular specific directive for that. Maybe something like ngonchange or ngonselect.